# Determining the value of an item at any specific location on a list

Tags: c#

I have a list with multiple values ranging from 1 to 52.

```
List<int> allCards = new List<int>(52);
```

I want to determine the magnitude of the value at this specific point of the list

```
allCards.RemoveAt(this._totalCardNumber);
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. RemoveAt does not return a value. The magnitude of the value where? What is _totalCardNumber?

Comment: So I have a list:    List<int> allCards = new List<int>(52);  This list as 52 different values in it and I want to remove one value at the specific location: allCards.RemoveAt(2) and I want to know how I can determine the value at that specific location of the lsit

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to get the value of an element in the list?

If that is the case, just use the indexer property of the list (assuming it's a `List<int>` or something like that.

e.g.

```
var value = list[_totalCardNumber];
```

Comment: So I have a list: List<int> allCards = new List<int>(52); This list as 52 different values in it and I want to remove one value at the specific location: allCards.RemoveAt(2) and I want to know how I can determine the value at that specific location of the list.

Comment: Caio's answer should point you in the right direction. The number 2 is the index of the item being removed so the value at that specific location will be the value of allCards[2].